# Linear recurrence sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

My question is following.

Let $(\xi_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a positive sequence which satisfies the following inequalities, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$

$\xi_{2n+1}\leq \frac{1}{2}\xi_{2n}+\frac{1}{2}\xi_{2n-1}$

$\xi_{2n+2}\leq \frac{1}{2}\xi_{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2}\xi_{2n-1}$

and I want to prove the convergence of this sequence. Ideally, I want a generalisable proof with more terms, or with different comportements. For example,

$\xi_{3n+1}\leq \frac{1}{2}\xi_{3n}+\frac{1}{2}\xi_{3n-1}$

$\xi_{3n+2}\leq \frac{1}{2}\xi_{3n+1}+\frac{1}{2}\xi_{3n-1}$

$\xi_{3n+3}\leq \frac{1}{2}\xi_{3n+2}+\frac{1}{2}\xi_{3n-1}$

Thank you.

Comment: Consider $\xi_n = -n$, then $\xi_{2n+1} = -2n-1 \leq -2n + \frac{1}{2}$ and $\xi_{2n+2} = -2n-2 \leq -2n$...

Comment: I thought i precised positive sequence. Sorry !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let us derive a weaker, but simpler set of inequalities by plugging in the first inequality into the second to arrive at
\begin{align*}
\xi_{2n+1} &\leq \frac{1}{2}\xi_{2n} + \frac{1}{2}\xi_{2n-1} \\
\xi_{2n+2} &\leq \frac{1}{2}\xi_{2n+1} + \frac{1}{2}\xi_{2n-1} \leq \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{1}{2}\xi_{2n} + \frac{1}{2}\xi_{2n-1} \right) + \frac{1}{2}\xi_{2n-1} = \frac{1}{4}\xi_{2n} + \frac{3}{4}\xi_{2n-1}.
\end{align*}
Now, let $M_n = \max\{\xi_{2n+1},\xi_{2n+2}\}$ and $m_n = \min\{\xi_{2n+1},\xi_{2n+2}\}$.
Then, since 
\begin{align*}
\xi_{2n+1} &\leq \frac{1}{2}\xi_{2n} + \frac{1}{2}\xi_{2n-1} \leq \frac{1}{2}M_{n-1} + \frac{1}{2}M_{n-1} = M_{n-1} \ \text{and} \\
\xi_{2n+2} &\leq \frac{1}{4}\xi_{2n} + \frac{3}{4}\xi_{2n-1} \leq \frac{1}{4}M_{n-1} + \frac{3}{4}M_{n-1} = M_{n-1},
\end{align*}
the sequence $M_n$ is monotonously decreasing and, since it is bounded below by $0$, converges to some $M \in \mathbb{R}$. On the other hand, at least one of $\xi_{2n}$, $\xi_{2n-1}$ equals $m_{n-1}$, therefore,
\begin{align*}
\xi_{2n+1} &\leq \frac{1}{2} m_{n-1} + \frac{1}{2}M_{n-1} \\
\xi_{2n+2} &\leq \frac{1}{4} m_{n-1} + \frac{3}{4}M_{n-1},
\end{align*}
i.e. $M_n \leq \frac{1}{4} m_{n-1} + \frac{3}{4}M_{n-1}$, which implies $M_{n} - m_{n-1} \leq 3 (M_{n-1}-M_n)$, which converges to $0$. Thus, $m_n \rightarrow M$ as well.

This method will always work as long as the right hand sides of the inequalities are recurrent convex combinations of the type presented in your two examples.

It might be worth noting that, if the sequence is not bounded below, it will still either converge or diverge to $-\infty$, since if $M_n$ is monotonously decreasing but not bounded below, $\xi_n \rightarrow -\infty$ trivially.

Comment: Ok, it is pretty interesting. But I don't know how to solve my problem with it. Because in your case you don't have any gap (between $2n+1$ and $2n-1$ in the even case). I will try to write your method for my problem.

Comment: @nm001 Ok, I added the details for the step where the original system is transformed to the one without the gaps, sorry for being unclear about that.

Comment: Ok thank you, it is clear now. I don't understand how you prove that $\xi_{2n+2}\leq \frac{1}{4}m_{n-1}+\frac{3}{4}M_{n-1}$. You say that one is equal to $m_{n-1}$ (I agree that), but you seems to choose $\xi_{2n}=m_{n-1}$.

Comment: I understand now. Just because $\frac{1}{4}m_{n-1}+\frac{3}{4}M_{n-1}\geq \frac{3}{4}m_{n-1}+\frac{1}{4}M_{n-1}$. Thank you. I just check the other points, and I will validate this answer !